# Sharepoint Site with Excel Sheet Template for Users to create New Sheets

Tags: sharepoint

I am tasked in work with creating a share-point site.
Here are my requirements:

The main page must allow the user to create a new "File".

The file must be an excel sheet template that i will style to my liking.

After the user creates a new "File", the Excel sheet is opened in the webpage for them to edit. They can save it and reopen later.

Many other users will create new "files" also - same process - same template. If i change the template then any new files use the new template.

When files are created the user must put it into a section that high level describes the location of our plant that the "file" is relevant for . e.g Some users will put files under the "Company Shipping category" category and others the "Company receiving category".

Any user can search any or all "files" for full textual searches and also within categories of our company plant (as described in item Above)

Is all this possible and  what is the easiest method - Any examples of this would be great.

Thanks,
Damo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is all built in SharePoint functionality.  You can create a document library with a default file template using excel.  The document library can have added columns called metadata to track the high level descriptions. SharePoint has built in search functionality.

The best way is to get a SharePoint administration book and start reading.  There are also a lot of contractors that specialize in setting up SharePoint.

**EDIT**: 
Here is a [tutorial video](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-server-help/sharepoint-document-libraries-i-an-introduction-RZ101930528.aspx) and here is the [second part](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-server-help/sharepoint-document-libraries-ii-organize-and-configure-a-library-RZ102410290.aspx) on setting up a document library and adding advanced features like metadata columns.